# Maven: Missing artifact javax.ejb:ejb:jar:2.0

Tags: maven, ejb, maven-2, ejb-2.x

I have noticed a strange thing: in Maven central repository are available the releases of `ejb-api` and `javax.ejb-api` (both based on ejb 3.x), but the old `ejb 2.0` is not avaliable:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/ejb/ejb/2.0/

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/ejb/ejb/2.1/

There are only the xml or pom, but not the jars.

If I try to include this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I have the error:

```
Missing artifact javax.ejb:ejb:jar:2.0
```

Why there is this difference instead of ejb-api 3.x ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These earlier versions of the EJB APIs (and many others) were licensed products that required the user to agree to the licence before using them.

Consequently they could not be made freely available in Maven repositories or anywhere else.

If you look in the actual pom files you will see that they contain (now obsolete) instructions for downloading the artifact jars.

An organisation would typically download them and install them into a local repository manager such as Nexus or Artifactory.